# Flink Twitter Connector - How to avoid exceeding rate limit (420)

Tags: twitter, flink-streaming

## Question

Is there a way to control the frequency (rate) of Twitter API access from the 
[Twitter Connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/twitter.html) to avoid 420 that can be caused from [Rate Limiting](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limiting.html) ?

#### 420

> Returned when an app is being rate limited for making too many requests.